# Yii2 UploadedFile::saveAs() is not saving file

Tags: yii2

Trying to upload file:

```
public function uploadFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    //  $this->image = $file;
    $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@web').'uploads/'.$file->name);
    var_dump($file);
    die();
}
```

But the file does not appear in the destination directory.

Dump:

> object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#150 (5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_0005.jpg" ["tempName"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpDFnzQp" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["size"]=> int(877612) ["error"]=> int(0) }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@web` alias points o base **URL** of app. If you want to save file on disk, you need to use file path instead of URL - you can find it in `@webroot` alias:

```
public function uploadFile(UploadedFile $file) {
    return $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '/uploads/' . $file->name);
}
```